# Initiation values for runtime and reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, new-operator

For a hobby project, I'am trying to solve the following problem:
I try to get the initialisation values with which a class instance is made also available in reflection. Currently I only know how to do this by using an attribute for reflection and the new DoubleParameter(...) to set the values runtime:

```
[MyDoubleSettings(-10,10,5)]
public DoubleParameter param2 = new DoubleParameter(-10,10,5);
```

I would like to know if there is some way to only have these values in the code once. This construct will be used many times and someone is bound to only change one or the other. 
I couldn't find a way to use reflection to see the new DoubleParameter(...) values. Also I couldn't find a way to see the attribute from the DoubleParameter class.

Is there any way to do this or is there some other neat way to solve this?

Kind regards, 
Ernst.

Comment: You would also have to use Reflection in the constructor.  That's not great, a factory method is strongly indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an attribute.If all you want to do is to get values of some fields or properties you can do that easily using `Reflection`, for example if you have three **public** property that holds these values you can use the following:

```
var values = typeof(DoubleParameter)
             .GetProperties()
             .Select(x => x.GetValue(yourInstance))
             .ToArray();
```

You can also cast result of `GetValue` to `double` if you sure that the type of your properties is `double` or filter them based on property type:

```
var values = typeof(DoubleParameter)
             .GetProperties()
             .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(double))
             .Select(x => (double)x.GetValue(yourInstance))
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work on runtime reflection. I am trying to do reflection from an external tool. Then there is no instance (yet).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to get the arguments passed inside an attribute constructor:

(*Also I couldn't find a way to see the attribute from the DoubleParameter class*)

```
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass _testClass = new TestClass();
        Type _testClassType = _testClass.GetType();

        // Get attributes:

        // Check if the instance class has any attributes
        if (_testClassType.CustomAttributes.Count() > 0)
        {
            // Check the attribute which matches TestClass
            CustomAttributeData _customAttribute = _testClassType.CustomAttributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(TestAttribute));
            if (_customAttribute != null)
            {
                // Loop through all constructor arguments
                foreach (var _argument in _customAttribute.ConstructorArguments)
                {
                    // value will now hold the value of the desired agrument
                    var value = _argument.Value;
                    // To get the original type:
                    //var value = Convert.ChangeType(_argument.Value, _argument.ArgumentType);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[TestAttribute("test")]
public class TestClass
{
}

public class TestAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(string _test)
    {
    }
}
```